# How to create add and delete textfields in tableview by using XIB

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, xib

There is one table view cell xib file which has two text fields  Name and phone. When I click on Add button, the same cell should repeat with the delete button. On click of delete button that row should delete. It's like multiple additions or deletion of text fields in UITableview.

How to do this in Swift?

Comment: You will have to use tableview delegate methods for row addition and deletion, keep track of number of rows and do some simple mathematical calculation.

Comment: You need to provide more information on what code you already have?  Do you have the UITableView all setup.  Also make your requirement clearer.  Do you mean the cell will show an 'Add' button and then when you click that  the 'Add' button is replaced by the 'Delete' button or that there is now an 'Add' and 'Delete' button or is it that there is a new copy of that cell with a 'Delete' button.  What are you actually trying to achieve overall?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth There is a cell which has a text field. Add Button is not in UITable view, it's outside the table view. When I click on Add button it should repeat the cell with the delete button.  So I can delete the current row also which I have added. As there is no array for showing the table view, Its just text input text field.

Comment: I see.  You should edit the question to reflect the extra information as it's important.  Also edit the question with details of what code you already have or have tried.  At the moment we have no idea of the setup you currently have at all.

Comment: I think, It may helped you- https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960